# Look and feel of datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Does anybody have a clue about this date picker are looking like this??

[image]

I wrote a partial view to added the attribute to the textbox

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new { data_datepicker = true });
```

Are this affecting the resulting datepicker??

Comment: is all the css loading properly?

Comment: i think so, i used `charles debugging proxy` and all the css are loading great, at least that are missing some css this are the css that are injected `jquery.ui.theme.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would immediately assume an issue with CSS. verify you have the correct CSS and everything is loading

Comment: It might be useful to start with a nice css reset file, and a cacheless reload

Comment: @Evan: Indeed -- it appears at least a couple sprites for the icons have their rules messed up.

Comment: it's correct are missing the file called `jquery.ui.base.css`